# ksh script for existence of file

Tags: windows, cygwin, ksh

Always i get "Source file not readable or exists, please check the file " for the below code. I use cygwin in my windows machine to run the script. I am getting the same message even when the file is present in the location. How can i get more details as why the file is not readable.

```sh
#!/bin/ksh
#
# Scanning source file for existance and readable
file_loc="abc.xml"
if [ -f "$file_loc" -a -r "$file_loc"]
then
    print "Source file read.\n"
else
    print "Source file not readable or exists, please check the file $file_loc.\n"
fi
```

Comment: For a start, try breaking down the problem: is it the `-f` or the `-r` test that's failing, for example?

Comment: Both ksh93 *and* bash give me a `missing ']'` or `']' missing`. Which shell did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space before the closing bracket is needed:

```
if [ -f "$file_loc" -a -r "$file_loc" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
file_loc="abc.xml" && (< ${file_loc:?})
```

is an alternative check. An advantage is that it returns different messages for different errors; we let the shell do all the work.

How is this constructed? This single line can trigger at least three different messages:

The `${` varname `:?`  optional message `}` syntax will check for undefined variables,
which can signal a typo in the variable name.

```
(< ${file_lo:?} )
```

`-bash: file_lo: parameter null or not set`

`(<` filename `)`  will just attempt to open and close the file.

```
$ (< nonesuch ) && echo ok
```

`-bash: nonesuch: No such file or directory`

```
$ (< /etc/shadow ) && echo ok
```

`-bash: /etc/shadow: Permission denied`